# Ajax Request is sent more than once in a DataTable Delete action - ASP.NET, JQuery, Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

AJAX sent more than one request each time the function is called (ASP.NET MVC, Ajax and JQuery)

I have a webpage that has a table (using JQuery Datatable) and each row in the table has a delete button that holds the id of each row. The Id is used to send a Delete request to a Web API(in the same project) and, if the Id is correct, it will delete the row.

It works just fine if I use just once the button. However, if I click the button for one row (so it gets deleted), then, click to delete another row, I realized that the request is sent duplicated to the Web API, with both the Id of the previous call and the current call.

For that reason, the server will throw a NotFound error for the Id that had been deleted and, for the current id, it will delete just fine.
If I repeat with another button, it will send, then, three delete request.

I'm not an expert with Javascript (or ajax or jquery), so I couldn't figure out what I can do to solve it.
(I saw similar posts, but I couldn't find something that works in my case)

**HTML to create each row:**

```
// Note that it uses a data-customer-id to data attribute to hold the value
foreach (var customer in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            // ( unrelated code) 
            // DELETE BUTTON
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link js-delete" 
                    data-customer-id="@customer.Id" data-toggle="tooltip"         
                    data-placement="right" title="Using JQuery & AJAX">Delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#customers").on("click", ".js-delete",function() {
            //getting a reference for the button to be used when it's clicked
            var button = $(this);

            // call the modal (display the dialog box on the screen)
            $("#deleteModal").modal();

            // if the deleteConfirm button is clicked
            $("#deleteConfirm").on("click", function () {
                var urlLog = button.attr("data-customer-id");
                $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",       
                        success: function () {
                            // case it's success, remove the row from the table
                            button.parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                });
                // hide de modal (dialog box)
                $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");
            });      
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Ouput in the Network tab in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uubPN.png)

I was expecting that each click to a delete button would send only one request to the WebApi, not multiple requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are attaching an event listener to your `#deleteConfirm` element every time you click on `.js-delete`.

Refactor and move your `$("#deleteConfirm").on("click", function () ...` function outside of the `$("#customers").on("click", ".js-delete",function() ...` block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'm trying to solve like that, however, since I remove one "click function" from the other, I cannot keep the reference of which button invoked the second click function. So, in the end, I couldn't delete the right row
(the object goes as an array of object and it deletes always the first one, not my selection)

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code following the suggestion above and separated both click functions.

Ps. If I kept both functions as they were in the beginning, one inside the other, I could use this code for the second click function it also works

```
$("#deleteConfirm").off().bind("click", function ()
```

In the end, the final script was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#customers").on("click", ".js-delete",function() {
                //getting a reference for the button to be used when it's clicked
            var button = $(this);

            // STORE THE REFERENCE TO THE BUTTON
            $("#deleteConfirm").data('ref', button);
            // call the modal (display the dialog box on the screen)
            $("#deleteModal").modal();

        });

$("#deleteConfirm").on("click", function () {
                //var button = $("#customers .js-delete");
                // get the reference to the button
                var button = $(this).data('ref');
                $.ajax({

                    //url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                    url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                    method: "DELETE",       
                    success: function () {
                        // case it's success, remove the row from the table

                        button.parents("tr").remove();                                
                    }
                });


                // hide de modal (dialog box)
                $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");
            });      

        });
```